# put kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape at the bottom of the screen

Tags: size, admob, banner

I am trying to put `kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape` at the bottom of my screen.

Here is my code. Please help.

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape] ;
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"AD ID";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.. Create a blank View at the bottom with size of 0, 678, 1024, 90 for ipad and similarly for ipod. And then add bannerView_ as a subview of that newly created View